# Golang rsa x509 ParsePKIXPublicKey error

Tags: go, rsa, x509

I'm getting some strange situation with parsing just-created rsa keys.

**In this part I generate new pair and write into file:**

```
rsaKey,err:= rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader,2048)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

publicKey := rsaKey.PublicKey

outFile, err := os.Create("./private.pem")
defer outFile.Close()

var privateKey = &pem.Block{
    Type:  "PRIVATE KEY",
    Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(rsaKey),
}

err = pem.Encode(outFile, privateKey)


asn1Bytes, err := asn1.Marshal(publicKey)

var pemkey = &pem.Block{
    Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
    Bytes: asn1Bytes,
}

pemfile, err := os.Create("./public.pem")
defer pemfile.Close()

err = pem.Encode(pemfile, pemkey)
```

**Next step is reading key from file and parse it:**

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./public.pem")

block, _ :=pem.Decode(data)
res,err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
fmt.Print(err)
```

But **x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)** return error:

> asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:2 length:257 isCompound:false}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false defaultValue: tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} AlgorithmIdentifier @4

**playground example**

https://play.golang.org/p/djlK8lO5_E2

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Try to marshal your public key with `x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(&publicKey)` instead of `asn1.Marshal(publicKey)`

Comment: @fl9 ty. its works!